# How to filter Cosmos DB data based on value of an element in an array of values Using SQL API

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a cosmosDB collection with below Data in it.
I have to find out the data only for EVENT named ABC and its value using SQL query.

```
[
    {
        "ID": "01XXXXX",
        "EVENTS": [
            {
                "Name": "ABC",
                "Value": 0
            },
            {
                "Name": "XYZ",
                "Value": 4
            },
           {
                "Name": "PQR",
                "Value": 5
            }
           ]
       },
       {
        "ID": "02XXXXX",
        "EVENTS": [
            {
                "Name": "ABC",
                "Value": 1
            },
            {
                "Name": "XYZ",
                "Value": 2
            },
           {
                "Name": "PQR",
                "Value": 3
            }
           ]
       }
    ]
```

I have tried the below code but it is not working since EVENT is an array.

```
SELECT * FROM c where c.EVENTS.Name = 'ABC'
```

Is there any way to find filter out the data only with Event Name as ABC using SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try using join

```
SELECT c FROM c
 join l in c.EVENTS 
 where l.Name = 'ABC'
```

[image]

Comment: @Antony I noticed that your sql contains `c.EVTS`, i'm afraid that's the issue.

Comment: @Antony It should be `c.EVENTS`,rignt?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am getting the result as above. But this is like we are getting the entire event lists when a record is having event named ABC. Is there any way to get only the event ABC from those lists ?     Like result should have only ID and data of Event named ABC only.